# Looking for an example of an icon and tooltip next to invalid field using jQuery validation in MVC3 or 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I saw an example on the web but now cannot find it any more.

What I would like to do is to have an exclamation mark icon appear next to fields that fail jQuery validation and then have a tooltip or bubble that show the error message when the user hovers over the icon. I know there are examples out there on the web but just cannot find what I am looking for any more.

Has anyone implemented this kind of functionality for their MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://www.sdinternet.co.uk/validation-tooltip-example/test.php) uses the jquery validation and tooltip plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [one example](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/asp-net-mvc-displaying-client-and-server-side-validation-using-error-icons/) using qTip.

Answer (score 0):

here is a detailed example of what you want:

http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/asp-net-mvc-displaying-client-and-server-side-validation-using-qtip-tooltips/